# How do you parse and modify a .odg file using Python?

Tags: python, libreoffice

I have an existing odg file that I need to modify through Python.

I've looked at ezodf library, but it's not well documented for odg files:

https://github.com/T0ha/ezodf

I don't see any relevant examples to go off of.

```py
import ezodf
draw = ezodf.opendoc('diagram.odg')
# can't get any further than here
```

`draw` will print 
`<ezodf.document.PackagedDocument object at 0x7f50f295a550>`, but I need to parse this and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be looking for a third-party solution, but have you considered straight Python-UNO? Use the method `oDoc.getDrawPages()`.

- Some documentation: [The Structure of Drawings - Basic](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Structure_of_Drawings)
- Python example: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=24920

To get started with Python-UNO, use [APSO](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python) and an introspection tool such as [MRI](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/mri-uno-object-inspection-tool).